# Remove app related downloads when app removed from device

Tags: ios, swift

I currently download some files to custom folders in the users documents directory on the device.  Like the below directory for the simulator.

```
/Users/Genie/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A2FB00CE-B018-4FDF-9635-35FD6678DF8D/data/Containers/Data/Application/8E04CE2A-D3BF-49FD-99EA-34ABABA84BBE/Documents
```

which is got with this code:

```
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
var userDirectory = String(describing: paths[0])
if userDirectory.hasPrefix("file://") {
    userDirectory.removeSubrange(userDirectory.startIndex..<userDirectory.index(userDirectory.startIndex, offsetBy: 7))
}
```

What happens if the app is removed from the device?  i assume the files would stay where they are?  Should i put them somewhere more specific to this app so they are removed automatically?

Im very unsure about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As you are adding the files in the document directory, When you remove the app files will also get removed too. Because the files are within the context of the application and not stored anywhere else in the device. And also you can't store it anywhere else except cloud. So your files will be removed once you delete the app.

Comment: But why sometime the reinstalled app knows my login info? which means I do not need to re-enter the credential again

Comment: @LiXinyang That might be if you are storing the credentials.

Comment: @LiXinyang Might be in keychain.

Comment: Thanks @parthadroja

Comment: @LiXinyang Welcome would be appreciated if you upvote if your queries are resolved.